# Swipe tabs inside one specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Inside my app I am using navigation drawer for my navigation. For each "page" I am using fragments (like showed here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). It works completely fine, but now I want to create swipe tabs. I want to display those tabs only on one of the fragments. Problem is, that tabs are displayed on all fragments, which is ofcourse perfectly normal because tabs are inside action bar. What should I do, to display tabs only on one fragment?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, you are interested in showing action bar only in a particular fragment (not visible when swiping in subsequent fragments). The best way would be to code the action bar in fragment instead of using the action bar in main fragment and then creating swipe views (or sub fragments).

Hope it helps.